# Javascript locating hidden field

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with an arbitrary number of rows. In the first cell in each table is an image with an onclick call to a javascript function, and a hidden field with the ID of the row. The call to the javascript function looks like:

```
<td>
    <a href="#" onclick="doSomeAction(this); return false;" title="Do Something">
        <img src="<?php echo($this->baseUrl());?>/images/btn_add.png" width="20" height="20" alt="Add" />
    </a>
    <input type="hidden" name="rowid[]" value="123" />
</td>
```

In my Javascript, I would like to retrieve the value of the id[] field. I tried to access it as follows:

```
var x = obj.parentNode.childNodes;
var i,j = x.length;
for ( i=0; i<j; i++ ) {
    if ( 'rowid[]' == x[i].nodeName.toLowerCase() ) {
        inp.value = x[i].value;
    } else {
        inp.value = 999;
    }
}
```

In all cases, this returns 999 as the value, indicating that it cannot locate the child node. What is not being done correctly here?

Comment: Are you duplicating `rowID[]` as a value for more than 1 row? IDs need to be unique.

Comment: Yes - but you can do that to get an array of fields.

Comment: Your if condition is converting it to lower case whereas you have ID in caps.

Comment: @Elie only on Name, not on ID, and if I'm not mistaken, that's only for server-side code like PHP, not JavaScript.

Comment: The [] piece is meant for the name, not the ID so that you can get an array when it's passed to the server.

Comment: Yes, what @cwolves said.

Comment: You're right, ID should not use it. But that isn't the problem here, since making that change makes absolutely no difference to being able to reference the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x[i].nodeName` is the name of the element, e.g. INPUT, A, TD, DIV, etc.  If you want to keep down this path, just check `.name` or `.getAttribute('name')`

Also, x should probably be `obj.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes` since the parentNode is the A tag.

Comment: Tried both methods - checking to see if the item was an INPUT element, and checking for getAttribute('name'). I also tried checking both levels of parent, but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: never mind my last comment - I forced it to go up to the row, then back down (so parentNode.parentNode.cells[0]) and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If the  following block appears in a loop you could assign ids to all html elements and then IMHO, you just need to pass that ID to ur JS method
`while a loop runs{
    <td id="the-tr-$id">
    <a  id="the-tr-href-$id" href="#" onclick="doSomeAction(this, $id); return false;" title="Do Something">
        <img id="the-tr-href-img-$id" src="<?php echo($this->baseUrl());?>/images/btn_add.png" width="20" height="20" alt="Add" />
    </a>
    <input type="hidden" name="rowid[]"  id="the-tr-input-$id" value="123" />
</td>
}`

and in your method, you can do a `document.getElementById()`

I would recommend assigning IDs to all html elements, if it seems too much then important elements do need IDs, always helps.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution - of course, being able to pass the id as a value to the function means that I can always be sure I'm getting the correct value, and much more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

```
alwaysFalse = 'rowID[]' == anyString.toLowerCase()
```

Comment: transcription error in my post, correcting that now. In my original, the quoted string was all lowercase.